# How to randomly choose N items from array and associate them with the right item from another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have two numpy arrays of 4 items each. The i item of the first array is correlated with the i item of the second array, and so on. I need to randomly choose N items from the first array, but I'd like to keep the 'association' with the second one, so that if I pick item #2 from the first array, item #2 of the second one is chosen too.

A sample of the code I'm currently using:

```
data = np.array([13170.06, 12552.34,  12420.39, 12336.24])
data2 = np.array([6217.69,  12242.05,  9218.21,  5095.23])

choice = data[np.random.choice(len(data), size=1, replace=False)] #In this way I pick 1 item
```

Basically, if the code samples 13170.06, I need to associate something like choice2 = 6217.69, or in any case to pick the same i-item also from the second array.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick an index randomly and then use that index on both arrays:

```
random_index = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(data)), size=1, replace=False)
data[random_index]
data2[random_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about generating the index randomly and then pick the elements from both arrays.
E.g.:

```py
index = np.random.randint(len(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combine both arrays into one numpy matrix

```
res = np.vstack((data,data2)).T
```

Later you could pick one random sample which will contain both corresponding elements

```
sample = res[np.random.choice(len(data))]
elem1 = sample[0]
elem2 = sample[1]
```